# IDA Hex-Rays structure inline functions recognition

Tags: ida, c++, hexrays, decompiler

I've seen multiple posts about the subject, but mine is a little bit more specific about what I want to achieve.

I have many times situations where Hex-Rays decompiler outputs 16 lines of code and I know this is a call to a inline structure function.

So the first step, I convert those 16 lines of code to a structure (i.e `Matrix`) which makes it a little bit more clear to understand what's happening

Then I'm stuck where I want to make it show as 1 line, which will call to the underline inline structure function `Identity()`.

So those 16 lines of code:

[image]

Would show as `s_mtx.Identity()` or maybe `Identity(s_mtx)`

Is that even possible doing it within HexRays decompiler? Maybe some script I can write to do that?

This gets really tedious when you have a function with many matrix multiplications, vectors etc...

Maybe @IgorSkochinsky?

Thanks a lot in advance!